# Short way to assign several attributes to the same object in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a short way to do this:

```
user.first_name = "first"
user.last_name = "last"
user.email = "e@mail.com"
```

Something like this:

```
with user:
  first_name = "first"
  last_name = "last"
  email = "e@mail.com"
```

is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is ActiveRecord object then:

```
user.assign_attributes(
  first_name: "first"
  last_name: "last"
  email: "e@mail.com"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `block`? `ActiveRecord` have many ways for this:

```
User.new.tap do |user|
  user.name     = "John Doe"
  user.username = "john.doe"
  user.password = "john123"
end
```

or:

```
User.new do |user|
  user.name     = "John Doe"
  user.username = "john.doe"
  user.password = "john123"
end
```

or mix initialize:

```
User.new(name: "John Doe") do |user|
  user.username = "john.doe"
  user.password = "john123"
end
```

or super simple with `update()`:

```
user.update(
  first_name: "first"
  last_name: "last"
  email: "e@mail.com"
)
```

Comment: `tap` is not from `ActiveRecord` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap

Comment: @IS04 i know about it.i don't say that `tap` method available only in `AR`

Answer (score 0):

for non ActiveRecord you can use instance_eval method, eg:

```
class SomeClass
   def a(*args)
     @a ||= args
   end

   def b(*args)
     @b ||= args
   end
end

2.0.0 (main):0> some_class_instance = SomeClass.new
=> #<SomeClass:0x007f9b62b629c0>
2.0.0 (main):0 > s = "a 'a args'
2.0.0 (main):0 * b 'b args'"
=> "a 'a args'\nb 'b args'"

2.0.0 (main):0 > some_class_instance.instance_eval(s)
=> ["b args"]
2.0.0 (main):0 > some_class_instance.a
=> ["a args"]
2.0.0 (main):0 > some_class_instance.b
=> ["b args"]
```